# Cassandra Latest value on each key

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I am trying to model a history stream of user... Think like twitter, each record have three column:

```
userid, posted_time, message
```

If my primary use case is retrieving the lastest tweet from ***all*** user. Is there any simple way to model this in Cassandra?

In sql, it would be

```
select * from t where (userid, posted_time) in (select userid, max(posted_time) from t group by userid);
```

But I don't think it is possible in Cassandra.

Comment: This is similar to what was asked in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/535LyWOJKsc . Seems it have no build-in solution.

Comment: Why do you want to query all users at once? What is your use case for that data?

Answer (score 0):

For Cassandra you must denormalize your data so the queries you expect to perform are efficient. So, if you want to find the time of the latest update by a user, you should have a table that has the user ID as its key and the time of the latest update as the value.

Comment: I want to find latest messages from _each_ and _all_ user.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table tblname(userid varchar,
posted_time timeuuid,
message text,
primary key(userid,posted_time)
)with clustering order by (posted_time desc);
```

After following schema

```
Select * from tblname where userid='id' limit 1
```

will give latest record for each user
Also you can order the result by posted_time

Comment: It is possible to get latest message for _all_ user without looping them all?